# Why is this model not rendered like in blender?

Tags: model, libgdx, render, blender

I am still struggling with rendering models in libgdx, so I did the following simple test:

- Download of a model: http://www.blender-models.com/model-downloads/characters/id/survival-character/
- Open the model in Blender and export via the Addon: https://github.com/Dancovich/libgdx_blender_g3d_exporter
- Load and show the model like described in many samples

The result does look like in the right image below. What am I missing?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UDZP.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stretching of the object is most likely from the object scale settings in blender.

[image]

In blender press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and select Scale (or rotation and scale), this will set the objects scale to 1.0 while keeping the same size.

[image]

The reduction in geometry will be from the subsurf modifier not being applied before exporting.

[image]

Click apply in the subsurf modifier before exporting.